Uniform PDF over the contour of a triangle
Problem definition
Consider a triangle with vertices $V_1,V_2,V_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Consider the following parametrization
\begin{equation*}
z(\alpha) =\underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^3 \left[(V_{j+1}-V_j) \frac{L}{L_j} \left(\alpha-\frac{\tau_{j-1}}{L}\right)+V_j\right]1_{\left[\frac{\tau_{j-1}}{L},\frac{\tau_{j}}{L}\right)}(\alpha)}_{\triangleq \psi(\alpha)}
\end{equation*}
where

$V_4\triangleq V_1$
$L_j\triangleq \lVert V_{j+1}-V_j\rVert$
$\tau_0\triangleq 0$, $\tau_j\triangleq\sum_{i=1}^j L_i$
$L\triangleq \tau_n=\sum_{i=1}^n L_i$
$1_S(x)=1$ if $x\in S$ and $1_S(x)=0$ otherwise

I would like to show that if $\alpha$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$ then $z$ is uniformly distributed over the triangle perimeter.
My difficulty
Let's assume for the moment that $z$ is distributed over some surface $\mathcal{S}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$. In that case, my strategy would be to show that the PDF of $z$, given by
\begin{equation*}
p_z(z)=\frac{p_\alpha(\psi^{-1}(z))}{|\textrm{det} J_\psi(\psi^{-1}(z))|}
\end{equation*}
is constant. In the formula above $|\textrm{det} J_\psi|$ is the absolute value of the determinant of the Jacobian matrix of the parametrization $\psi(\alpha)$. Since $\alpha$ is uniform, i.e. constant, the problem reduces to proving that $|\textrm{det} J_\psi|$ is constant.
Now, let's go back to my problem. If I'm not wrong, since $z$ is distributed over a curve (which is a set with Lebesgue measure - i.e. area - null), it is not possible to define a conventional PDF $p_z(z)$. Hence, I have to prove the result without using densities.
My attempt
Instead of using the density, my strategy is to directly use the probability measure $\mathbb{P}(\ell)\triangleq \textrm{Prob}(z\in \ell)$ and show that
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{P}(\ell)= \frac{\textrm{length}(\ell \cap \mathcal{C})}{\textrm{length}(\mathcal{C})}
\end{equation*}
where $\ell \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a measurable set and $\mathcal{C}$ is the triangle contour. Let $p_\alpha(\alpha)$ be the uniform density of $\alpha$, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
p_\alpha(\alpha)\triangleq 1_{[0,1]}(\alpha)
\end{equation*}
then
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(\ell) &=\textrm{Prob}(\alpha \in \psi^{-1}(\ell))\\
&=\int_{\psi^{-1}(\ell)} p_{\alpha}(\alpha) \text{ d}\alpha \\
&=\int_{\psi^{-1}(\ell) \cap [0,1]} \text{ d}\alpha\\
&=\frac{\int_{\psi^{-1}(\ell) \cap [0,1]} \text{ d}\alpha}{\int_{[0,1]} \text{ d}\beta}\\
&=\frac{\textrm{length}(\psi^{-1}(\ell) \cap [0,1])}{\textrm{lenght}([0,1])}\\
&=\frac{\textrm{length}(\psi^{-1}(\ell) \cap [0,1])}{\textrm{lenght}([0,1])}
\end{aligned}\end{equation*}
Now, $\psi(\alpha)$ is affine and so it scales the length of $\psi^{-1}(\ell)\cap[0,1]$ and  the length of $[0,1]$ in the same way. Thus,
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(\ell)&=\frac{\textrm{length}(\psi(\psi^{-1}(\ell)\cap[0,1]))}{\textrm{length}(\psi([0,1]))}\\
&=\frac{\textrm{length}(\ell\cap\psi([0,1]))}{\textrm{length}(\psi([0,1]))}\\
&=\frac{\textrm{length}(\ell\cap \mathcal{C})}{\textrm{length}(\mathcal{C})}
\end{aligned}\end{equation*}
Questions
I'm not sure if my proof is formally correct because I'm not an expert in real analysis and measure theory. Thus my questions are:

Is my conclusion correct?
Given that my conclusion is correct, is my proof formally correct?
Is it correct my argument about the density $p_z(z)$?

